# WP8 .design file implement into application

Tags: windows-phone-8, icons, blend

I have a design file of an Icon that I created in Expression Blend so I could use it as a the tile for my app, I am just wondering how do I implement it into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Expression Blend: save your icon as .png
- VisualStudio: Import the .png into your WP project
- VisualStudio: Open Properties/WMAppManifext.xml, select your .png as Tile Image

let me know if i didn't get your question right